# TfsAreaAndIterationProcessorOptions configuration2.json

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

I am looking at the source code and configuration2.json file and the processor TfsAreaAndIterationProcessorOptions which has the ability to specify a Query that is unique for both the Source and Target. Is it possible to use different queries to migrate based on Area Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TfsAreaAndIterationProcessor` does not use queries and is only used to migrate Area and Iteration nodes. You can filter those nodes.